# Error while install FiPy "Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1"

Tags: python, pip, fipy

I'm trying to install FiPy on Python 3.6. and ran into trouble. I followed the installation instruction from the NIST website: https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/INSTALLATION.html

But at the last step `pip install fipy` I get an error that I don't understand:

> (MYFIPYENV) >pip install fipy Collecting fipy   Cache
>   entry deserialization failed, entry ignored   Cache entry
>   deserialization failed, entry ignored
>   Downloading FiPy-3.1.3.tar.gz
>
> ```
> Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-9xzf0bmv\fipy\setup.py",
> line 61
>     except ImportError, e:
>                       ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> ----------------------------------------
> ```
>
> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
>   C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-9xzf0bmv\fipy\ Cache entry
>   deserialization failed, entry ignored

Could someone please tell me what's this error about and how to fix it?

To not dupplicate the question I tried following hints:

```
>pip upgrade 
>pip install --upgrade setuptools
>pip install ez_setup
```

Working on Windows 10.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FiPy is a Python 2 package.

- You can convert the code to Py3k with `2to3`:
  https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/documentation/USAGE.html#running-under-python-3
- You can use conda to maintain side-by-side Py2 and Py3k installations. Conda is our [recommended pathway](https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/INSTALLATION.html#recommended-method) these days, anyway. Those instructions [need to be modified](https://github.com/usnistgov/fipy/issues/530) to ask for a specific python version:

  `conda create --name <MYFIPYENV> --channel guyer --channel conda-forge fipy nomkl python=2.7`

Comment: I converted the code yet however the installation failed. Tried your second hint and got:

(base) C:\Users\>conda create --name MYFIPYENV --channel guyer --channel conda-forge fipy nomkl python=2.7
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - fipy
  - gmsh
  - fipy
  - pysparse
  - fipy
  - trilinos
  - fipy
  - nomkl
  - nomkl

Comment: Yes, I see that the conda installation does not work on Windows. I'll investigate. What does "I converted the code yet however the installation failed" mean? I just did a clean python 3.6 install on a Windows VM, ran `2to3`, and installed. The code runs. What happened when you tried? What exact steps did you take?

Comment: C:\Users\\Diss_py\conda\envs\envfipy\Scripts>2to3 --write .
RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: buffer
RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: idioms
RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: set_literal
RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
RefactoringTool: No changes to .\2to3-script.py
RefactoringTool: No changes to .\easy_install-script.py
RefactoringTool: Refactored .\f2py.py
--- .\f2py.py   (original)
+++ .\f2py.py   (refactored)

Comment: @@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
 #!C:/Users/Diss_py/conda/envs/envfipy\python.exe
 # See http://cens.ioc.ee/projects/f2py2e/
-from __future__ import division, print_function
 import os
 import sys
RefactoringTool: No changes to .\futurize-script.py
RefactoringTool: No changes to .\idle-script.py
RefactoringTool: No changes to .\mayavi2-script.py
RefactoringTool: No changes to .\pasteurize-script.py
RefactoringTool: No changes to .\pip-script.py
RefactoringTool: No changes to .\pydoc-script.py
RefactoringTool: No changes to .\pygmentize-script.py
RefactoringTool: No changes to .\tvtk_doc-script.py

Comment: RefactoringTool: No changes to .\wheel-script.py
RefactoringTool: Files that were modified:
RefactoringTool: .\2to3-script.py
RefactoringTool: .\easy_install-script.py
RefactoringTool: .\f2py.py
RefactoringTool: .\futurize-script.py
RefactoringTool: .\idle-script.py
RefactoringTool: .\mayavi2-script.py
RefactoringTool: .\pasteurize-script.py
RefactoringTool: .\pip-script.py
RefactoringTool: .\pydoc-script.py
RefactoringTool: .\pygmentize-script.py
RefactoringTool: .\tvtk_doc-script.py
RefactoringTool: .\wheel-script.py

Comment: C:\Users\Diss_py\conda\envs\envfipy\Scripts>2to3 --write --doctests_only .
RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: buffer
RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: idioms
RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: set_literal
RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
RefactoringTool: No files need to be modified.

C:\Users\\Diss_py\conda\envs\envfipy\Scripts>pip install fipy

Comment: Collecting fipy
  Using cached FiPy-3.1.3.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-eu3gp3ys\fipy\setup.py", line 61
        except ImportError, e:
                          ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-eu3gp3ys\fipy\

Comment: Sorry for this long comment. I code for my phd in python 3.6 in spyder 3. Now I need a PDE-solver and there is not really an alternative to fipy.

Comment: I have no idea what source code you converted, but it wasn't FiPy. Download a copy of the FiPy source code from https://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/download/FiPy-3.1.3.win32.zip. Unzip this source and then from within the unzipped directory, run the `2to3` commands in our documentation. After running `2to3`, then run `python setup.py install`.

Comment: `2to3` is a command installed with python, not a python module. Change into the FiPy source directory you unzipped. Run `2to3 --write .`. Run `2to3 --write --doctests_only .`. Run `python setup.py install`. See also https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html

Comment: I had to go the extra mile to learn. Thanks a lot for you patient help. It works now.

Answer (score 1):

```
except ImportError, e:
```

The syntax is for Python 2 only. Seems FiPi can be used only with Py2. Or at least can only be installed with Py2 using `pip`. Try other installation methods.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions? I'm kind of lost.

Comment: Use conda for installation. Or use Python 2. Or update the code to be Py3-compatible. Or ask the authors to update code.

Comment: The authors [have](https://github.com/usnistgov/fipy/pull/473) [been](https://github.com/usnistgov/fipy/pull/490) asked, and are not unsympathetic, but it's not been a priority because none of the good (3rd party) solvers work on Py3k and it's so trivial to run python 2.7 and 3.6 side-by-side with conda.